# how to integrate Yodlee FastLink with mobile app

Tags: yodlee

I am trying to integrate Yodlee FastLink with mobile via HTML/JavaScript but no luck. Any other alternative to this?

Comment: Can you add more details about what issue are you facing? And whether it is Android or iOS?